# Filter state that is set from onClick as data- in react

Tags: reactjs

Two main issues. 
(1) onClick needs to update two items in my state
(2) I need to filter state #2 to count the number of times a string appears and render it if it equals the length of state#1

More Detail:

I am mapping through my objects and rendering a button for each. I need the onClick to setState of two different attributes so i pass value={item.item} to update state selectedItems , and data-matches={item.matches} to update state of matchesList.

-- note that item.item is a string and item.matches is an array of strings.

When I call onClick to update the state, the value works fine, but the data-matches creates a weird object which i cant iterate over and this is why thats a problem...

I need to map through the data-matches state and count each instance of a string, if the count of that particular string is equal to the length of selectedItems state, then I need to render that.

If this is confusing to you, it's because I am completely lost and new to this. Maybe its worth mentioning that my props are coming from Redux..

Example of some objects for reference

```
{
'item': 'apple',
'matches': ['beef', 'bacon', 'cheese', 'carrot'],
},
{
'item': 'carrot',
'matches': ['apple', 'bacon', 'goat'],
},
```

```
export class Items extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      selectedItems: [],
      firstStep: true,
      matchesList: []
    };
    this.selectItems = this.selectItems.bind(this);
    this.filterMatches = this.filterMatches.bind(this);
  }
```

```
selectItems(event) {
    this.setState({
      selectedItems: [...this.state.selectedItems, event.target.value],
      firstStep: false,
      matchesList: [...this.state.matchesList, event.target.dataset.matches]
    });
  }
```

Below, in the col 'All", I am mapping through my state selectedItems which is an array, so I can grab the actual object from props which is the same name. I then map over the matches array of that object, and grab the actual object that has the same name as the matches...

in the col 'Cross Referenced", I am mapping over the state updated from the onClick. This is where I need to filter.. I'll show you my attempt at that after this code block.

```
render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
<div className="col">
              <div className="row">
                <div className="col-5">
                  <h1>All</h1>
                  {this.state.selectedItems.map(selected =>  
                    this.props.items.map(item =>
                      item.item == selected
                        ? item.matches.map(match =>
                            this.props.items.map(item =>
                              item.item == match ? (
                                <div>
                                  <p>{item.item}</p>

                                  <button
                                    key={item.item}
                                    value={item.item}
                                    data-matches={item.matches}
                                    onClick={this.selectItems}
                                  >
                                    Select
                                  </button>
                                </div>
                              ) : null
                            )
                          )
                        : null
                    )
                  )}
                </div>
                <div className="col-5">
                  <h1>Cross Referenced</h1>
                  {this.state.matchesList.map(matches => (
                    <p>{matches}</p>
                  ))}
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

My attempt at filtering, even though the matchesList is not right.

```
  filterMatches(matchesList, selectedItems) {
    let arr1 = matchesList;
    let arr2 = selectedItems;

    let obj = arr1.reduce((op, inp) => {
      let key = inp;
      op[key] = op[key] || 0;
      op[key]++;
      return op;
    }, {});

    let final = Object.keys(obj).filter(key => {
      return obj[key] === arr2.length;
    });
    return final;
  }
```

in the render

```
<div className="col-5">
  <h1>cross referenced</h1>{this.state.matchesList.filter(this.filterMatches(this.state.matchesList, this.state.selectedItems)).map(matches => (
  <p>{matches}</p>
  ))}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried out the data-matches thing, and it looks to me like `event.target.dataset.matches` was coming out to be a string (Not an array of strings, one big CSV string). Try doing it the following way:

```js
class YourComponent extends React.Component {

  state = {...};

  selectItems = (item, matches) => {
    this.setState({
      selectedItems: [...this.state.selectedItems, item],
      firstStep: false,
      matchesList: [...this.state.matchesList, ...matches]
    });
  }
  
  render() {
   return (
      {...}
      {this.props.items.map(item => (
        <button
          key={item.item}
          value={item.item}
          onClick={() => this.selectItems(item.item, item.matches)}
        >
          Select
        </button>
      ))}
      {...}
    );
  }
  
}
```

Actually I think I see what your issue is, the filter is working fine and it's already giving you your array of `["bacon"]`. Try getting rid of the outer filter, I don't see a point to it being there.

```js
const YourComponent = props => (
  {...}
  {this.filterMatches(this.state.matchesList, this.state.selectedItems).map(matches => (
   <p>{matches}</p>
  ))}
  {...}
);
```

Comment: Nice, thanks so much Anthony!! This solves the first issue, I know have a working array. However, I cant get the filter function to work based on my states

Comment: Can you give me an example input / output using the apple & carrot items? I'm having trouble understanding what your goal is.

Comment: Sure, so in that example, state.matchesList would be ['beef', 'bacon', 'cheese', 'carrot', 'apple', 'bacon', 'goat']. Bacon is the only match that appears the same length of state.selectedItems, 2 so id like to render Bacon. If you added in another object that you'd count for three, etc.

Comment: In that case your filter seems to be working fine. I plugged into a pen, everything seems to line up. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dEqRNv?editors=1111

Comment: Yep, that's the issue. `Array.prototype.filter` takes a function, and you're passing it the `["bacon"]` array. Just get rid of the outer filter and you should be good to go.